# Angular to send the get property value from parent to child component

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have parent component that will send the value to child component from get property. Value that is sent to child component is shown in the same parent HTML page but it is not reachable to child component.

Tried using new method, tried all the lifecycle to fetch the value from the parent component nothing was helpful, also i tried using Viewchild to some extent but neither that helped me to get the value.

parent.component.ts

```
get name(): string {
 return this.service.name.toLocaleLowerCase(); // returns the name Eg: Tom
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<child [name]="name"></child>
name::: {{name}} <!--display name as Tom in the parent HTML-->
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() name: string;
 constructor() {
  console.log(name); // logs unknown
}
```

The above console.log displays as unknown

i tried to console.log inside ngOnInit method - it displays unknown
i tried using ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) - but for some reason the value is not getting printed first time but second time it gets printed which  is not useful. 
Can anyone please suggest?

i need to fetch the input value inside contructor method.

Comment: You can't use `input` values inside a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think your child component is loaded before the service's name variable value is initialized. 
check service's value is already initialized and after that load your child component.

try with

```
<child [name]="name" *ngIf="this.service.name"></child>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to access the `@Input` value using `this` keyword

```
@Input() name: string;
 constructor() {
  console.log(this.name); //value passed from parent to the child
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use a [life cycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) in which inputs are set. Such as `ngOnChanges`, or `ngOnInit`
2. To access a member (class) variable in javascript/typescript you have to qualify it with `this`.

```
  @Input() name: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.name); // logs unknown
  }
```

Comment: sorry i used this.name i just missed adding in that question.. still it was not working